# Don't know how to use Cufon.refresh() on website with ajax

Tags: ajax, html, hyperlink, cufon

I have searched on this matter but havent been able to find an answer that work for me.

On my website I have one page with a menu and a div. When clicking on a menu link the information in the div changes (ajax). But then Cufón stop working in that div. I have read about Cufon.refresh but can't get it to work. Which code should I use and where do I put it?

My links look like this:`<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="getdata('kollektioner/kollektioner.html','myDiv');">test</a>`

I have read about Cufon.refresh at this page but I don't understand how to use it: https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/API

Comment: Based on the library in use, the ajax function should provide you with a callback once the data is loaded. Generally you call the Cufon.refresh() on the DIV once you have inserted the DOM chunk to the DIV (using the provided callback). To help any further people would need to know more details - code.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I still don't understand much. I'm completely new to Cufón and Ajax.

I use this ajax.js file: http://data.fuskbugg.se/skalman02/fd9ca231_ajax.js

The div that changes looks like this: <div class="myDiv"><p>Information...</p></div>

Answer (score 1):

`Cufon.refresh` also does not work for me. A workaround is to use `Cufon.replace` again.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the JS you are using, you can edit the trigger function to work like the below and see if that works. Essentially, it will refresh the Cufon call after you have updated the content on that element.

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) if (xmlhttp.status == 200)
{
    document.getElementById(ajaxdestination).innerHTML =xmlhttp.responseText;
    Cufon.refresh('#ajaxdestination');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tried to add that code to ajax.js but it didn't work. Sorry.